# Can't display german umlaut

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, str-replace

My main problem right now is that I can't display "ä, ü, ö" on my webpage, the get displayed as �, when I display my script with "echo" they seem normal, when I run it included from my html page I get �.

After I tried several things I've read on this topic I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm reading an .xls file with a .xls to php reader. I get the data from the fields like this:

```
function getMenueMonday($connection) {
    $menu = "";
    $startrow = 8;
    $endrow = 16;
    $col1 = 3;
    for ($i = $startrow; $i < $endrow; $i++) {
        $menu .= $connection->sheets[0]["cells"][$i][$col1] . "<br>";
    }
    return $menu; }
```

Which runs perfectly fine.
Then I'm saving all these return values in an array. I loop trough them to save them into a mysql database.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    insertMenue(changeAttr($menues[$i]), $days[$i]);
}
```

The method I'm using to change the letters is as following:

```
function changeAttr($content) {
    $search = array("ä", "ö", "ü", "ß", "Ä", "Ö", "Ü");
    $replace = array("&auml;", "&ouml;", "&uuml;", "ss", "&Auml;", "&Ouml;", "&Uuml;");
    $contentrep = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
    return $contentrep;
}
```

In the table of my database they still get saved as "ä, ö, ü".
The table itself is in **utf8_bin**.
I tried this in the header of the html file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<html lang="de">
```

as well as this in the file I use to read the db.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

With following code I get this output:

```
foreach($menues as $r){
    echo urlencode($r);
}
```

"Saisonfr%FCchte" where it should be "Saisonfrüchte".

Is there a point where I miss the charset or do something particularly wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your connection must be aware of the encoding you're using as well, otherwise some implicit character set conversion will take place. To achieve that, you can do:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Please refer to [this blog post](http://melp.nl/2011/01/about-mysql-utf-8-and-saving-headaches/) for a step-by-step explanation of common encoding errors when using MySQL and PHP.

If everyone is "speaking utf-8", there is no need for escaping the characters in your HTML using named entity references. It may even be considered bad practice.

Comment: Thank you! Just `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")` in the connection file works perfect!

Comment: `PDO: $db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pwd); `

Answer (score 0):

Well now actually everything after an "ä, ö, ü" doesn't get written into the database...
But if there was one in the db, it would be displayed correctly.

Comment: Probably because your data is corrupted. Please read the blog bost I referred to earlier, it will help you resolving this further.

Comment: By only using `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")` on the connection to read out it works